# How to remove rectange boxes in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to remove rectangle boxes in vs code while typing

[vs code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWaLz.jpg)
#vs_code

While typing rectangle boxes are coming any thing tapping or selecting

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by making a small change in vscode settings. All you need to do is open *Preferences*, go to the settings page, and search for **Match Brackets**. Under the *Text Editor* section, you'll find the **Editor: Match Brackets** option. To remove the brackets, change the value of this option to **never**.

[image]